# I am getting error in R.java .Do not know how to proceed?

Tags: android, code-generation

I am getting error with the generated java file. But the code is fine and good . Can any one give suggestion.

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: probably the error is in some xml file.

Comment: but there is no error showing in the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your image it appears that you are getting an error with the element with id of "enter", try changing the id of that element to something more descriptive and the error might go away.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which error you are getting. Usually you can resolve errors in R.java by removing it, and letting Eclipse regenerate it. If you still are getting the same error, you can try to rename the controls with the offending id.

If you wish further assistance, you need to say which error you are getting.